# NGINX default_server ssl redirecting everything

Tags: nginx

I am having an NGINX emergency where multiple websites are correctly defined as hosts with their URL set. The problem is when I make a default handler in NGINX all the SSL connections get redirected and fail. HTTP still works correctly with the default handler. I have specifically set server_name and yet it still redirects to default_sever.

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return       444;
}
server {
    listen       443 ssl default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return       444;
}
```

Comment: There are no redirects in the configuration you posted.

Comment: I didn't add the part for my websites since they work without the above code. I am assuming it is in the default_server implementation.

Comment: Have you configured ssl for your default server? What is the server name, is it an ip or a domain?

Comment: We cannot provide any answer without seeing the complete configuration, since it is the combination of all configuration items that define the behaviour of the system.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior might be due to incorrect configuration of SSL certificates. Try adding some kinds of certificates, like in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/846214/468247).

In my case, there was also something else missing:

```
ssl_session_tickets off;
```

Don't ask me why, without it the whole nginx was just broken. Nginx version 1.12.2.

The whole working example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    return 404;
}
```